# clear the form fields using jquery unform plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, uniform

I'm using jQuery [uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) plugin for forms. But the problem is, how do I clear the 'file' input?

I am using:

```
$("[name=radio]").removeAttr("checked");
$.uniform.update(".colorPicker");
```

for clearing the radio boxes.

Also using,

```
$("#file_upload").replaceWith("<input type='file' id='file_upload' name='file_upload'>").html();
```

to clear the file input.

Answer (score 1):

Try sample HTML

```
<input type='file' name='item1' id="test" />
<input type='button' name='item2' id='test1' value="Empty"/>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#test1").on("click", function(){
       $("#test").replaceWith('<input type="file" name="item1" id="test"/>');
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dYEBW/

Means using your code (**Update**):

```
$("#file_upload").replaceWith("<input type='file' id='file_upload' name='file_upload'>");
```

Comment: hi, i am using jQuery uniform plugin, here below the name of the file the photo also u can visible.

Comment: See **UPDATED** code, it must work no matter what plugin you use OR see the event or function which do this.

Comment: The code clear the input **NOT** form. Somewhere in your code is wrong ... It works for me and I used also some jquery form plugin. See the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
$("#file_upload").empty();
```

Comment: Sometimes won't work because some browsers blocked the content access to input type file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the field by using val() method of jQuery api. So the code is shown below:

```
$("#test1").on("click", function(){
       $("#test").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = $('input[name=file_input]');
input.val('');
$.uniform.update(input);
```

Works 100%.